# Setting SneakyButton sprite using CCFrameCache

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to set the SneakyButton sprites from CCFrameCache? 
Nothing shows up when I try :

```
[exitBase.defaultSprite setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] 
                                         spriteFrameByName:@"exitUp.png"]];
```

It works fine with a `[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@""]` statement

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your batchnode normally, then setup SneakyButton with spriteWithSpriteFrameName:

```
SneakyButtonSkinnedBase *sneakyBut = [[[SneakyButtonSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
sneakyBut.position = ccp(444,280);
sneakyBut.defaultSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sneakyButtonOff.png"];
sneakyBut.activatedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"sneakyButtonOn.png"];
sneakyBut.button = [[SneakyButton alloc] initWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 90)];
sneakyButton = [sneakyBut.button retain];
[self addChild:sneakyBut];
```